# IndexOutOfBoundsException after repopulating ArrayList (Marshmallow only)

Tags: java, android, arraylist, android-asynctask, android-6.0-marshmallow

My setup is as follows: inside my onCreate I initialize an ArrayList as follows:

```
textList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

// unrelated code ...

if (isConnected()) {
    new DisplayTextTask().execute(sectionId);
}
```

and the AsyncTask fetches text via `HttpURLConnection()`, parses the json using `JsonReader`, and adds each line of text to the textList (all of this happens inside the AsyncTask's `doInBackground`. I have a custom Adapter that displays the strings in `textList`.

I also have a function `gotoNextSection()` that gets triggered when the user wants to navigate to the next page, where I do something like:

```
gotoNextSection() {
    if (isConnected()) {
        new DisplayTextTask().execute(sectionId+1);
    }
}
```

However, since I don't want the stale text from the previous page to remain on screen, I do the following in my AsyncTask:

```
private class DisplayTextTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        textList.clear();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
        // json parsing is called in getData()
        try {
            return getData(urls[0]);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return "Could not load text";
        }
    }
```

so that the arrayList is empty and ready to be repopulated. **All of this works fine in all other supported Android versions but when I tried it in a Marshmallow emulator `gotoNextSection()` results in an IndexOutOfBoundsException.** This occurs after the new content is added to the freshly cleared arrayList (verified via logging), so I don't think it's a race condition. Note that not clearing the list prevents the exception, and since this is the only ArrayList used in the Activity I'm positive that `.clear()` is the problem. I've tried nulling and reinitializing it before launching the AsyncTask as an alternative as well, to no avail. **Again, this happens exclusively on Android 6.0.** Thoughts?

EDIT:
Here's the logcat stacktrace. Note that the size of index that it's attempting to access and where in the code this occurs is irrelevant because I've tried to log the ArrayList after the task is executed in `gotoNextSection` and it just gives me an exception for whatever index I've tried to access in the log.

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
        at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
        at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
        at android.widget.HeaderViewListAdapter.isEnabled(HeaderViewListAdapter.java:164)
        at android.widget.ListView.dispatchDraw(ListView.java:3329)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:16181)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.draw(AbsListView.java:4142)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:15174)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3593)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3573)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:15134)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3593)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3573)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:15134)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3593)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3573)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:15134)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3593)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3573)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:15134)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3593)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3573)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:15134)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3593)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3573)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:15134)
        at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateViewTreeDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:281)
        at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateRootDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:287)
        at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.draw(ThreadedRenderer.java:322)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:2615)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw(ViewRootImpl.java:2434)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2067)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1107)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6013)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:858)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:670)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:606)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:844)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: show logcat stacktrace

Comment: without the logcat, i don't have a clue. one thought may be that on 6.0 the Clear() method might have been changed.  i would try a alist.removeAll(alist) to see if clear is the problem, and if so, would report it to google as android M is still on proview and there is no stable release out yet.

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK updated with logcat

Comment: @irvanjit: please post `HeaderViewListAdapter ` class code

Comment: @CptEric ^. Tried removAll, same thing happens.

Comment: @user3676184 sectionId is just an int that tells getData which page to fetch. It's irrelevant because the data exists and displays when the ArrayList isn't cleared.

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK will post when I can, but I took a closer look at my adapter class. The exception occurs when I try to access the ArrayList in the adapter. What ended up working was if I disconnect the adapter from the list view in pre execute, and then call clear on the ArrayList and reconnect the adapter in post execute. This results in a significantly longer delay though because I have to init a new adapter every time. Perhaps Google is more strict with how resources are managed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved: I ended up having to disconnect the adapter from the ListView before calling clear and reconnecting it afterwards in postExecute(), I'm guessing Marshmallow is more strict about data binding

Comment: Why not use RecyclerView? How come you develop for M, but you still use ListView?